# Sum using Lambda function and Variable argument

Tags: python, lambda

I am new to lambda functions. I am trying to get the sum of elements in a list, but facing this issue repeatedly.

[image]

When following up with tutorials online([Tutorial-link](https://realpython.com/python-lambda/)). The following code is working fine for them. But, I am facing the same problem.

[image]

**Can someone help me to understand why is this happening?**

Comment: Looks like you may have overwritten the built-in `sum()` function with a lambda.

Comment: Your code works fine as is: https://ideone.com/j8WiA8 I think @jasonharper is probably correct...

Comment: @Nick, I have been trying to get rid of the error. But, to the best of my knowledge, I have not created any sum function to overwrite it.

Comment: did you try the `sum()`function normally, without lambda or anything, can you ensure that your `sum(list)` works correctly and gives the sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sum = __builtins__.sum
li = [5, 7, 22, 97, 54, 62, 77, 23, 73, 61]
l = lambda *x: sum(x)
l(*li)
```

If it works, then that means you have overwritten `sum` somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
fun = (lambda *x: sum(x))
print(fun(*l))

print((lambda *x: sum(x))(1,2,3))
```

Output:

```
10
6
```

Comment: But the same code is not working for me. I just want to know the reason so that I can fix this in my code. Can you please provide me the way to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
l = (lambda *x: sum(x))
print(l(*li))
```

Try this code, this is executing correctly.

[Screenshot of the answer executed in Tutorialspoint python interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnrCt.png)

Comment: we all know the code is working, so the copy answer wont be helpful, it should be a config error maybe

Comment: I'm not sure about Jupyter notebook config,that's why I tried in my local and online interpreters as well. It is working.

Comment: ya it is working for all cases, but not his

Answer (score 1):

You're facing this problem because you must have defined a function named `sum` somewhere in your current jupyter-notebook session.

Please change your code like this-

```py
import math

li = [1,2,3]
l = lambda *x: math.fsum(x)
l(*li)
```

Let us know if you're still getting the same error.